# как checkbox передать значение true в переменную при нажатии галочки на checkbox?

Tags: javascript

```
<div id="input">
<div class="number">
<label for="third">первое: </label>
<input type="checkbox" id="third" value=true/>
</div>
<div id="button">
<a href="#" onclick="onButtonClick()">Кнопка</a>
<br>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="checkbox" id="third" value=true onclick="truee=this.checked"/>
```

Comment: оно всеравно только одно значение передает

Comment: @recile Это Вы с кем сейчас разговариваете )? А сколько значений надо? Что значит "только одно"? Разве в вопросе говорится о нескольких значениях?

Comment: изменил, значит не правильно написал да когда включена true когда отключена false

Comment: от нее принимает все время true, независимо включена она или нет